# text-overflow: ellipsis doesn't work after line break in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have a problem with `text-overflow: ellipsis` not working in Internet Explorer when there is text separated by a line break.

In Firefox and Chrome, both lines of text get truncated with an ellipsis. In Internet Explorer, the first line gets truncated with the ellipsis and the second line just truncates on the right.

Here is my code:

```css
.text-wrapper {
  border: solid 1px #C2C2C2;
  padding:10px;
}
.text-wrapper p{
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-wrapper" style="width:250px;">

    <p>
      This line overflows and gets an ellipsis in any browser. 
      <br/>
      This line overflows and gets an ellipsis in any browser except IE.
    </p>

</div>
```

Comment: it used to be this way in any browsers, for this behavior, pre was required. wich , still, didn't work in IE. Is this a bug ? not sure about what W3C says about behavior expected ... https://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-text-20021024/#text-overflow-props

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [**`text-overflow`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow), ellipsis can be applied to a single line of text.

The following CSS requirements must be met:

- must have a `width`
- must have `white-space: nowrap`
- must have `overflow` with value other than `visible`
- must have `display: block` or `inline-block`

It would appear that IE is actually rendering the ellipsis correctly: *The second line should not have ellipsis.* This makes it multi-line in effect, violates the intention of `nowrap`, and ellipsis should fail.

The fact that Chrome and Firefox render the ellipsis after line breaks is possibly an implementation difference they've taken upon themselves.

One workaround would be to create new paragraphs instead of line breaks.

For ellipsis on multi-line text consider these options:

- [jQuery dotdotdot...](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/)
- [Line Clampin’ (Truncating Multiple Line Text)](https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/)
- [CSS Ellipsis: How to Manage Multi-Line Ellipsis in Pure CSS](http://www.mobify.com/blog/multiline-ellipsis-in-pure-css/)

Comment: one line is the actual behavior that should be expected, but variants and tuning is on its way https://www.w3.org/wiki/Text-overflow_middle_cropping

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I separated the text into multiple paragraphs and that worked.